# How to convert x y z points into x y z spheres

Tags: meshlab

I have a file containing xyz point co-ordinates and would like to convert each point into a sphere using MeshLab.

From what can see so far most of the functions are tailored towards creating meshes and surfaces, but I just want to retain the points and transform each point into a sphere.

I am new to working with point cloud data and 3d transformations so appreciate suggestions and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a filter named **`Create Solid Wireframe`** in the [pre-release version of meshlab](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab) that do exactly what you are asking for. It is located in the 'Filters'->'Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction' menu. The bad news is that, being still in the development version, you need to recompile meshlab on your computer. It is quite easy following [these instructions](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/tree/master/src), or you could try one of the pre-release builds published at:

- OSX: https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/releases
- Windows: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/cignoni/meshlab/build/artifacts

The filter allows to create Spheres from each vertex of a mesh (or points of a cloud) with a given radius. Also can create other structures (edges->cylinder and face->Prism).

[image: Create Solid Wireframe filter]

Another "trick" you can use in meshlab 2016 version is to render points using a `Dot Decorator` which make them be showed as flat round dots. You can later change the color and size of the dots. They are really not spheres, but can be enough.

[image: Dot decorator]

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate the answer. We ended up heading in a slightly different direction to write an OpenSCAD file and then render and export STL to Blender. But some of the new solid transformation features look useful for transitioning from points to objects.